# angular crud delete method

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to create a delete method but it doesn't work, I use json-server with reactive forms, my description of the problem is quite simple because what I ask is quite simple
I'm a junior trying to figure out how it all works.

i have an error : ERROR TypeError: product is undefined

**ts.file**

```
export class ProduitsComponent implements OnInit {

  public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Produit>;

  constructor(private produitService: ProduitService, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLatestProduct();
  }

  createNewProduct(product: any) {
    this.produitService.createProduct(product).subscribe((response: Produit) => {
      let t = this.dataSource.data;
      t.push(response);
      this.dataSource.data = t;
    });
  }

  updateLatestProduct(product: Produit) {
    this.produitService.updateProduct(product).subscribe(response => {
      let index = this.dataSource.data.findIndex((value) => {value.id === product.id});
      this.dataSource.data.splice(index, 1, response);
    });
  }

  getLatestProduct() {
    let resp = this.produitService.getAllProduct();
    resp.subscribe(result => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Produit>();
      this.dataSource.data = result as Produit[];
    });
  }

  delete(product: Produit) {
    this.produitService.deleteProduct(product).subscribe(() => {
      this.dataSource.data.filter((value, key) => {
        return value.id != product.id;
      });
    });
  }
```

**service**

```
 public deleteProduct(product: Produit) {
    return this.httpClient.delete(`${this.urlProductApi}produits/${product.id}`);
  }
```

**html**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

   ......

    <!-- Comment Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="comment">
        <th class="text" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Commentaire</th>
        <td class="text2" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.comment}} </td>
    </ng-container>


    <!-- Action Column-->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="editFormDialog(row)">Edit</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="delete()">Supprimer</button>
        </td>
        </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `delete()` by adding `row` object as parameter in template like below to get the corresponding delete object

```
<button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="delete(row)">Supprimer</button>
```

Comment: I have this error :​ message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/produits/1: 404 Not Found"

Comment: Please check the rest url, seems there is typo.. ('products')

Comment: I don't see any typo

Comment: then this delete api call might not exist in server side, check the server code to confirm and do appropriate changes..